# CSS syntax Highlighting in c# with regex

Tags: c#, css, syntax-highlighting

I want to add CSS syntax highlighting to my rich text box in C#. How would I do that using regex e.g. highlighting the tag names/classes/id's. I have this so far for HTM, but I would like to do for CSS too.

```
            string tags = @"<([/A-Za-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)";
            tagMatches = Regex.Matches(rtb.Text, tags, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            // getting attributes from the text 
            string attributes = @"[A-Za-z0-9-_]*=[A-Za-z0-9-_]*";
            attributeMatches = Regex.Matches(rtb.Text, attributes);

            // getting comments (inline or multiline)
            string comments = @"(\<![ \r\n\t]*(--([^\-]|[\r\n]|-[^\-])*--[ \r\n\t]*)\>)";
            commentMatches = Regex.Matches(rtb.Text, comments, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            // getting strings
            string strings = "(\".+?\"|\'.+?\')";
            stringMatches = Regex.Matches(rtb.Text, strings);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern to match classes/ids: `([\.#][_A-Za-z0-9\-]+)[^}]*{[^}]*}`.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/z0Zle1/2)

Comment: `([\.#_A-Za-z0-9\-][_A-Za-z0-9\-]+)[^}]*{[^}]*}` this would be better

Comment: How would I do it for CSS properties? I have ben working on this for a while now and got nowhere. Thanks if you could help

Comment: Don't worry I worked it out for the properties [@Zroq](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6454584/zroq)
Here `string attributes = @"([A-Za-z0-9-]*:)";`